# returning a linkedhashset to xpage as multivalue

Tags: java, xpages, linkedhashset

In a my applications I have defined a property of an object as a LinkedHashSet. The property I fill with values from a multi-value field:

```
Vector<String> ctrs = doc.getItemValue("countries");        
LinkedHashSet<String> items = new LinkedHashSet<String>();      
for (int i = 0; i < ctrs.size(); i++){          
    items.add(ctrs.get(i));
}       
employee.setCountry(items);
```

On an XPage I would like to display the values as followed:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputCountries" value="#{employeeBean.employee.Country}">
    <xp:this.multipleSeparator><![CDATA[#{javascript:var val = getComponent("contractType").getValue();
if (val == "Multi"){
    return ",";
}}]]></xp:this.multipleSeparator>
</xp:inputText>
```

Depending on the type of employee this field may be single or multi-value.

When view the XPage the returned value is displayed as followed:

[Sweden, Denmark, Estonia]

Ofcourse I would have it displayed as multi-value. What should I do to correct this?

Comment: Did you try to use `xp:inputTextarea` (Multiline Edit Box) instead of `xp:inputText`?

Comment: both I tried. For the inputTextArea control I set the multi-value separator "\n" (computed) and , but same result here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you convert your HashSet to an Array then it should work

Here an example, the first as single/ the second as multi value field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:inputText id="singleValue" multipleSeparator=",">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var items:java.util.Set = new java.util.LinkedHashSet();
items.add("Sweden");      
return items.toArray();}]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:inputText>

    <br></br>
    <br></br>

    <xp:inputText id="multiValue" multipleSeparator=",">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var items:java.util.Set = new java.util.LinkedHashSet();
items.add("Sweden");
items.add("Denmark");  
items.add("Estonia");
return items.toArray();}]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:inputText>

</xp:view>
```

The output on a browser looks like:

```
Sweden

Sweden,Denmark,Estonia
```

Comment: Hello Georg, your approach works like a charm. Many thanks!

Comment: @Malin I am glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You must use List instead of Set.

In addition, unless you are using LinkedHashSet as a way to remove duplicate values from the Vector, you can just pass the `setCountry` method the vector because `Vector` implements `List`:

```
// setting country method
yourBlock() {
   // It's better to use interface instead of implementation for the variable
   List<String> countries = doc.getItemValue("countries");

   setCountries(countries);
}
```

If you do use `LinkedHashSet` as a way to get unique values you need to tweak the above code just a bit more.

```
// setting country method
yourBlock() {
   List<String> countries = doc.getItemValue("countries");

   setCountries(new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(countries)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In case you want just view the data**

Option 1: Split values with @Implode and some separator, coma or `<br/>` should work.

Option 2: Use repeat with custom rendering: multiple computed texts, divs or table.

**In case you want to edit data**

You need to use repeat. In that case you need to implement Map interface to your bean if you want to bind inputs. Good read is here: https://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/16.07.2009095816KLEBCY.htm?opendocument&comments